# Access Azure B2C Sign-In logs after 90 Days

Tags: azure, authentication, logging, azure-ad-b2c, audit

We are trying to overcome a situation where we need to **delete the users from Azure B2C directory** who have **not logged in for more than 90 days**. I am using the graph API, but it returns me the login history for max 30 days.

All searches I made direct me audit logs of Azure AD and not B2C (i presume, they are not the same). The graph API as well that i found for B2C was for audit logs and not just the sign in logs, which is also in beta version of the API only.

I need either help or alternatives on how this could be achieved. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a custom policy that is based on [this sample policy](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/disable-inactive-account) which:

- Creates a custom attribute called **extension_lastLogonTime**
- Updates this attribute value on sign-in

You can then execute an Azure AD API query for users that haven't signed in for 90 days or more.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, will try this out and comment/accept.
Thanks again.